# IE8 CSS and html vs IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Pardon any brashness here, I'm about at my wits end looking for answers.

I am looking for a list (if one exists) or some resource guide of specific html and css tags that have changed from IE7 to IE8. Specifically, I want to see something like "this code works in IE7 but not IE8... here is the broken tag's equivalent to make IE8 work."

I do NOT [begin frustration rant] want to hear anything about the meta x-ua-compatibility work around to put in my header.  We are FIXING our app for IE8, not putting on a band-aid.

Thanks in advance!

//sw

Comment: +1 for "FIXING our app..." . Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

I fear this is somewhat of a pipe dream :)

However, my solution is to use IETester. This has helped me enormously!

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: I just tried IETester - it's great!
I was a bit skeptical when I read the list of "Known problems and limitations" where it stated that Java applets are not supported, since I am developing a lot of map applications that use java applets. I was positively surprised when I discovered that my java applets works anyway!

Comment: That program suxs it continually crashes. Just do the leg work in install a Virtual Machine. Virtual Box is what i am currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the CSS differences, but IE8 and IE7 support HTML identically.  HTML, aside from HTML5, has not changed in more than 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html is by far the best resource for testing CSS differences between browsers. It is frequently updated, quick to scan, and very detailed and accurate. He has stuff on non-css differences as well but I find those sections less imperative.