# Browser Related UI issue

Tags: html, css

In IE7,I am getting some gap between two divs.

But in IE8,there is no gap.

How to get same gap in both browsers without using conditional-CSS ??

```
<html>
  <style>
    #layout_wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      border: 0px solid red;
    }

    #div_wrapper{
      width: 100%;
      border: 0px solid blue;
    }

    #container_02{
      width: 100%;
      border: 0px solid red;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="layout_wrapper">
    <div id="div_wrapper">
      <div name="container_01"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="div_wrapper">
      <div name="container_02" id="container_02"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: With this HTML and CSS is impossible to see any gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `height` property to `div_wrapper` css class I got same gap in both IE-7 and IE-8.

```
#div_wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px solid blue;
  height: 175px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both IE7 and IE8 support HTML identically, but there are some fundamental differences in CSS.

Have a  look at this [link](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm). It lists some common implementation differences between IE7 And IE8.
There's a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740749/ie8-css-and-html-vs-ie7) on the same issue.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!!